# Delete row with query doesn't working

Tags: php, mysqli, html-table, sql-delete

I found a way to delete rows from a table "dynamic", associating the id of each button to be erased, this id is taken from the table. 
Associate with each button this line of code:

```
"<td><form method='post' action='#'><a href=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?id=".$attivitaID."\" onClick=\"javascript:return confirm('Sei sicuro di voler cancellare questo prodotto?')\"><input type='button' value='Elimina' name='delete' id='back'></a></form></td>";
```

then run a check to see if it is pressed:

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])&& isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $connessione = new MySQLi(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

    $query = "DELETE FROM workpaper WHERE id = ?";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if (!$result)
    {
        die("Errore nella query $query: " . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_close();

  }
```

but the page is reloaded, without making any query, how can it?

Comment: did you make sure the <a>-tag is closed like <a href="..."> ... </a> ?

Comment: yes the tag is closed..

Comment: Does the form has the method set to POST?

Comment: i have updated the first line of code that post on this thread. I don't understand because not function :(

Comment: You are a little bit confused about form mechanism, your anchor ( <a> ) will not be submitted when you will press the button in the form, so the php code will never receive the id value... try to reformulate the problem (see my new answer ), anyway this is not the place to solve that kind of problem.

Comment: Ok, so how do I send the id of the page itself in order to enable the deletion?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is looking for something that appears to be something:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM workpaper WHERE id = ?";
```

Maybe you should add `$_GET['id']` as a value to the clause.

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM workpaper WHERE id = ?";
```

with:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM workpaper WHERE id = ".$_POST['id'];


"<td><form method='post' action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."'><input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$attivitaID."\" /><input type='button' value='Elimina' name='delete' id='back'></form></td>";
```